# WP-Ultimate-Search : order results by their content

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the plugin [WP-Ultimate-Search](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-search/) as a search engine.

It searches through my articles, by tags.

My articles don't have title, and I'd like to **order the results by article's** content.

I'm using a custom template

```
<?php if($wpus_results->have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while($wpus_results->have_posts()) : $wpus_results->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <div class="entry">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="separator"></div>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <div class="wpus-no-results"><?php echo wpus_option('no_results_msg'); ?></div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I can't use `$wpus_results->get_posts();` as it doesn't return all my results but only the results from the first tag ; so I can't reorder my results via a custom function.

Anyone has an idea?